AWS SAM deployment issue
AWS SAM deployment process specifically when attempting to upload a Docker image gives an error that Error: Unable to upload artifact signaturedetection:python3.8-v1 referenced by ImageUri parameter of SignatureDetection resource. ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')) the command i am trying to deploy is
sudo sam deploy --profile ml-dev --config-env dev --parameter-overrides $(cat dev-config.txt)
the error is not helpfull enough to let me know where the issue is comming from
i have tried searching online, changing sso profile and credentials and debugging the command as well folloing is the output for debug
2024-04-03 14:02:07,418 | Unable to export                                                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                              
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 715, in urlopen                                                                                                        
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request                                                                                                  
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 244, in request                                                                                                            
  File "http/client.py", line 1256, in request                                                                                                                  
  File "http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request                                                                                                            
  File "http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders                                                                                                               
  File "http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output                                                                                                             
  File "http/client.py", line 951, in send                                                                                                                      
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 27, in connect                                                                                                      
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                              
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send                                                                                                                
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 799, in urlopen                                                                                                        
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment                                                                                                          
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise                                                                                                          
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 715, in urlopen                                                                                                        
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request                                                                                                  
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 244, in request                                                                                                            
  File "http/client.py", line 1256, in request                                                                                                                  
  File "http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request                                                                                                            
  File "http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders                                                                                                               
  File "http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output                                                                                                             
  File "http/client.py", line 951, in send                                                                                                                      
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 27, in connect                                                                                                      
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                              
  File "samcli/lib/package/packageable_resources.py", line 287, in export                                                                                       
  File "samcli/lib/package/packageable_resources.py", line 300, in do_export                                                                                    
  File "samcli/lib/package/utils.py", line 128, in upload_local_image_artifacts                                                                                 
  File "samcli/lib/package/ecr_uploader.py", line 77, in upload                                                                                                 
  File "samcli/lib/package/ecr_uploader.py", line 64, in login                                                                                                  
  File "docker/client.py", line 197, in login                                                                                                                   
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 149, in login                                                                                                               
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 293, in _post_json                                                                                                          
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 44, in inner                                                                                                          
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 232, in _post                                                                                                               
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 637, in post                                                                                                                
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request                                                                                                             
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send                                                                                                                
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 501, in send                                                                                                                
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))                                                 
2024-04-03 14:02:07,436 | Telemetry endpoint configured to be https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics                            
2024-04-03 14:02:07,557 | Telemetry endpoint configured to be https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics                            
2024-04-03 14:02:07,560 | Sending Telemetry: {'metrics': [{'commandRun': {'requestId': '84f2ff7f-8858-48f2-bdcd-02f6ddb0811b', 'installationId':                
'db359fde-9221-42eb-8fc3-eb53812325e7', 'sessionId': 'd95f7d42-67bf-4f66-b178-11f9b6a58ebf', 'executionEnvironment': 'CLI', 'ci': False, 'pyversion': '3.8.13', 
'samcliVersion': '1.113.0', 'awsProfileProvided': True, 'debugFlagProvided': True, 'region': 'us-west-1', 'commandName': 'sam deploy',                          
'metricSpecificAttributes': {'projectType': 'CFN', 'gitOrigin': None, 'projectName': '6c571afbcfdf357e1abce06a2ea94b962ab0e17ed9327334d57cd55cab326406',        
'initialCommit': None}, 'duration': 46889, 'exitReason': 'ExportFailedError', 'exitCode': 1}}]}                                                                 
2024-04-03 14:02:07,560 | Unable to find Click Context for getting session_id.                                                                                  
2024-04-03 14:02:07,568 | Sending Telemetry: {'metrics': [{'events': {'requestId': '6453b935-996f-466a-9c42-2d088b737fde', 'installationId':                    
'db359fde-9221-42eb-8fc3-eb53812325e7', 'sessionId': 'd95f7d42-67bf-4f66-b178-11f9b6a58ebf', 'executionEnvironment': 'CLI', 'ci': False, 'pyversion': '3.8.13', 
'samcliVersion': '1.113.0', 'commandName': 'sam deploy', 'metricSpecificAttributes': {'events': [{'event_name': 'SamConfigFileExtension', 'event_value':        
'.toml', 'thread_id': 'ed43e6774fb0442f9e3d3cbb4de7d4a6', 'time_stamp': '2024-04-03 09:01:19.440', 'exception_name': None}, {'event_name':                      
'SamConfigFileExtension', 'event_value': '.toml', 'thread_id': '6e91df4924f34ecf8aaa3e7105b244fc', 'time_stamp': '2024-04-03 09:01:19.822', 'exception_name':   
None}]}}}]}                                                                                                                                                     
2024-04-03 14:02:08,450 | HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)      
2024-04-03 14:02:08,452 | HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)      
Error: Unable to upload artifact signaturedetection:python3.8-v1 referenced by ImageUri parameter of SignatureDetection resource.
('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

